# Indent in the first paragraph in the break style of ntheorem

Tags: ntheorem

I'm using `ntheorem` package to make my template. When I use `break` style, I found that the paragraph below the header doesn't have an indent, like this

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
    \begin{theorem}
        this is the first paragraph.

        this is the second paragraph.
    \end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

[image: break without indent]

I want it to have an indent like this

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
    \begin{theorem}
        \hspace*{\parindent}this is the first paragraph.

        this is the second paragraph.
    \end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't want to add the `\hspace*{\parindent}` every time when I use it. Is there a way to set it **globally**? I've tried to redefine the `break` style, but I didn't see where to control body's behavior.

```latex
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{break}%
  {\item[\rlap{\vbox{\hbox{\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator}\hbox{\strut}}}]}%
  {\item[\rlap{\vbox{\hbox{\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\ (##3)\theorem@separator}\hbox{\strut}}}]}
\makeatother
```

Comment: This behaviour is normal, since paragraph indentation is done  to visualise the start of a new paragraph, which is unnecessary here. It is for the same reason that we have no indentation of the first paragraph after a section title.

Comment: I know `indentfirst` package can handle indent of first paragraph after a section title. but I don't know how to deal with this "noindent'